# Custom heatmap theme in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization

What is the theme used in the graph shown below, or what similar theme can be used to create an appealing graph like the one in the provided photo? I saw the photo on the internet but no code was given. I have already sourced the code, but it's hard to interpret with the current theme.

[image]

As shown above, There is a `separate box` for each `week` and `age` combination. It is very easy to tell what were covid number in a particular week for a certain age group. Can someone tell what's the following theme, or suggest a similar theme to improve the graph's appearance for scientific audience?

Here is the reproducible example of my data

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    total_count = c(
      10L,
      0L,
      15L,
      0L,
      20L,
      0L,
      0L,
      50L,
      0L,
      6L,
      1L,
      10L,
      7L,
      0L,
      0L,
      29L,
      0L,
      2L,
      11L,
      3L,
      0L,
      12L,
      0L,
      30L,
      0L,
      0L,
      29L,
      44L,
      10L,
      5L,
      2L,
      145L,
      0L,
      70L
    ),
    mean_temp = c(
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82
    ),
    lwd_duration = c(
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-34L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  na.action = structure(
    c(
      `4` = 4L,
      `5` = 5L,
      `6` = 6L,
      `7` = 7L,
      `8` = 8L,
      `9` = 9L,
      `78` = 78L,
      `87` = 87L,
      `96` = 96L,
      `105` = 105L,
      `114` = 114L,
      `123` = 123L,
      `132` = 132L,
      `141` = 141L,
      `150` = 150L,
      `159` = 159L,
      `168` = 168L,
      `177` = 177L,
      `186` = 186L,
      `849` = 849L,
      `850` = 850L,
      `851` = 851L,
      `852` = 852L,
      `891` = 891L,
      `892` = 892L,
      `893` = 893L,
      `894` = 894L,
      `921` = 921L,
      `922` = 922L,
      `923` = 923L,
      `924` = 924L,
      `937` = 937L,
      `938` = 938L,
      `939` = 939L,
      `940` = 940L,
      `969` = 969L,
      `970` = 970L,
      `971` = 971L,
      `972` = 972L,
      `985` = 985L,
      `986` = 986L,
      `987` = 987L,
      `988` = 988L,
      `1017` = 1017L,
      `1018` = 1018L,
      `1019` = 1019L,
      `1020` = 1020L,
      `1033` = 1033L,
      `1034` = 1034L,
      `1035` = 1035L,
      `1036` = 1036L
    ),
    class = "omit"
  )
)
```

Code used to produce the figure:

```
dat2 <-
  df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    mean_temp = cut_interval(mean_temp, n = 10),
    total_count = cut_interval(total_count, n = 10),
  ) %>%
  group_by(mean_temp, total_count) %>%
  summarize(lwd_duration = mean(lwd_duration))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'mean_temp'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

ggplot(dat2, aes(mean_temp, total_count)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = lwd_duration)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(lwd_duration, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]

In my graph, I should have a separate box for the `mean_temp` [17.17, 17.6] and `total_count` [0, 14.5] combination with `total_count` 53.5 inside the box. Cells with values have merged, so it's hard to interpret. I don't want individual boxes overlapping. I have multiple observations in each cell. Suppose for one particular range of `mean_temp` combined with one range of `total_count`, I have values 5, 15, 100, so I had to use mean numbers. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the theme, this is because your data is not having every combination of `mean_temp` and `total_count`.

Comment: *"In my graph, I should have a separate box for the mean_temp [17.17, 17.6] and total_count [0, 14.5] combination with total_count 53.5 inside the box"* I assum the `17.17` is a typo for `17.1`, which does appear in your data. The bottom left box in your graph has `mean_temp [17.1, 17.6]` and `total_count [0, 14.5]` and a `53.5` inside the box. It is not missing. I think your plot accurately reflects the data you gave it, and I do not understand what changes you expect given that input.

Comment: Right, but I should still get a separate box for each `mean_temp` & `total_count` category? If there are no values, they are already left blank. They should not have any effect on cells overlapping each other?

Comment: You may want to add `+ scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to your plot to not drop x-axis values with no observations?

Comment: *"They should not have any effect on cells overlapping each other?"* I don't know what you mean by "cells overlapping each other". I don't see any overlaps.

Comment: You could change to `geom_tile(aes(fill = lwd_duration), color = "black")` to get an outline around each tile. Is that what you want?

Comment: *"Suppose for one particular range of mean_temp combined with one range of total_count, I have values 5, 15, 100, so I had to use mean numbers."* Yes, that is what you did. Looks good. Are you not happy with it? If not, what do you want/expect to see instead?

Comment: All I want is a `separate` box for each `mean_temp` , `lwd_duration` and `total_count` combination. Please see the COVID graph and my graph. `geom_tile(aes(fill = lwd_duration), color = "black")` has helped a bit. At the `left` corner of the plot, there should be `one` box for `for the mean_temp [17.17, 17.6] and total_count [0, 14.5] combination with total_count 53.5 inside the box`. These have occupied four boxes.

Comment: First cell at the bottom left in the covid figure, there is `one` box for values week 27, age less than 15 with 3.1 cases. I have four boxes for `mean_temp [17.17, 17.6]`  & `lwd_duration [0, 14.5]` with `53.5 lwd_duration`

Comment: The grid in the background can be removed by adding `theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())`

Comment: @Seth It's much better now. I have one box for each category. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  mutate(
    mean_temp = cut_interval(mean_temp, n = 10),
    total_count = cut_interval(total_count, n = 10),
  ) %>%
  group_by(mean_temp, total_count) %>%
  summarize(lwd_duration = mean(lwd_duration)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mean_temp, total_count, fill = lwd_duration)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'white', linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(lwd_duration, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'mean_temp'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>